# Checking the format/contents of a string

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, python-datetime

This program is intended to ask for the date as dd/mm/yyyy. It should then check to see if the user inputted the date in the correct format (dd/mm/yyyy). My program is not able to recognize the format correctly. This is my program:

```
date = (input("enter the date as dd/mm/yyyy: "))
date = day, month, year = date.split("/")
if date == (day + '/' + month + '/' + year):
    print (date)
    if len(day) == 1 or len(day) == 2:
        print("1")
    if len(month) == 1 or len(month) == 2:
        print("2")
    if len(year) == 4:
        print ("3")
else:
    if len(day) == 1 or len(day) == 2:
        print("4")
    if len(month) == 1 or len(month) == 2:
        print("5")
    if len(year) == 4:
        print ("6")
```

The numbers being printed currently have no other purpose than to just check the validity of the date. So far, only 4,5, and 6 are being printed, meaning my program is not recognizing the formatting of the date.

Comment: This is Python3, yes? It's crucial for this bit of code, so you may want to tag it as such.

Comment: You're reassigning `date` to a list and then expecting it to be equal to a string.

Comment: @Manaar you may want to see my edited answer to easily add vastly more functionality to your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

def checkdate(date):

    try:
        datelist = date.split('/')
        datetime.datetime(year=int(datelist[2]), month=int(datelist[1]),day=int(datelist[0]))
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you. Although the return function was not providing an output so I switched instead, to using a print() funtion

Answer (score 5):

Your solution doesn't work because `date=day, month, year = date.split("/")` sets `date` to a `list`, then you're comparing it to a `string` (`day + '/' + month + '/' + year`). However, your solution is a solved problem, do instead:

```
import datetime
date = (input("enter the date as dd/mm/yyyy: "))

try: datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y")
except ValueError: # incorrect format
```

In addition, you probably are turning this into a `datetime` object later on anyway, so you can do so in the `try` block!

As a further optimization, be aware that many users won't WANT to enter their dates using `/` as a datesep! Do some introspection on your input, and adjust your datesep appropriately.

```
date = input("enter the date: ")

if "-" in date: datesep = "-"
elif "/" in date: datesep = "/"
elif "." in date: datesep = "."
else: datesep = ""

if len(date) < 6: yeartype = "%y"
elif date[-4:-2] not in ("19","20"): yeartype = "%y"
else: yeartype = "%Y"

try: date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d{0}%m{0}{1}".format(datesep,yeartype))
except ValueError: # invalid date
```

Now your code will end up with a valid `datetime` object of Feb 2nd 2014 for:

- 02022014
- 222014
- 0222014
- 222014
- 020214
- 02214
- 2214
- 02-02-2014
- 02/02/2014
- 2-2-14
- 2/2/2014
- 2/2/14
- etc etc etc